# Can not Link/Connect Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle

I have been trying to connect Android studio 4.1 with Firebase but it is not getting linked. I followed the instruction given on the firebase website like copying the dependencies, plugins, etc. into the app Gradle build and Project Gradle Build. My Gradle version is 6.5 and Gradle plugin is 4.1.
The Error shown is:

org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression

org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
[image: Error Description]
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: I suggest doing a manual integration rather than using the Firebase assistant.  Follow the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: update the firebase plugin. it may solve the issue

Comment: Manual integration worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 57):

I believe i found the problem.
If you use

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to your `build.gradle`(module) like its instructed you get this error.

Instead change `apply plugin` to `id`

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I haven't finish the app but when I sync, [it's successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHhnM.png)

Comment: Thanks you. Cannot believe the documentation is wrong about such a fundamental thing.

Answer (score 9):

Using the Firebase guide to link my app with Firebase, the problem is that you have to scatter the plugins by these 2 ways of implementation:

```
//First way to implement plugins
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

//Second way to implement plugins
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Taking out the `apply plugin` ones from the {} of plugins solved my link issues ;)

Answer (score 9):

This Error Rise due to if you are using

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If You replace `apply plugin:` with `id` in build.gradle than this error will be solved.
**After change**

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6):

I do not know how correct this information is, however, I think you should remove the block of code

```
pugins{
  id '...'
}
```

Instead, start adding code/plugins like:

```
apply plugin: "com..."
```

Essentially all the plugins your firebase suggests. It works like magic and you do not have to lose the plugin.

[Example Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lReO3.png)

Answer (score 1):

//First way to use Plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

//Second way to use Plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding:

```
plugins {
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove Flower Parenthesis mention like this below with out flower brackets
whenever using apply plugins

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```